# Google Play Games Service achievements check

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'd like to know if there is some kind of local check when doing achievement unlock.

```
sGamesClient.unlockAchievement(getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_a_newcomer));
```

I have an achievement "Play a multiplayer game", but once a multiplayer game is done,
all the next multiplayer play will call line above but it's useless to call a server to check it, so is there some kind of local cache checking before communicating with play services server or do i have to implement it myself using Prefs  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem to call that method again: if the achievement is already unlocked, it won't  unlock it again, and it won't communicate with server, as these things are cached locally.